# Remove an item of a tree in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I try to remove an item in a QTreeWidget. How can I remove it ? I just want to remove it, not to delete it and I don't find any method.

Comment: Do you mean to hide an item?

Comment: what about takeTopLevelItem() API, to remove only ?

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly the method I was searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with takeTopLevelItem() API, It only removes the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QTreeWidgetItem::setHidden](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtreewidgetitem.html#setHidden) on the item you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

if have the item `QTreeWidgetItem` call `setHidden(bool)` you can get the titem by calling `topLevelItem(int index)` from the tree widget